# Printing behavior using fork() and write() in C

Tags: c, fork

In the following program, a fork() is called and one child is created. I understand that there is unpredictable output when using buffered output like in printf(). To get around that, I am using write(), which is unbuffered.

The problem is that write() is not printing the \n together with the string.

I have tried using setvbuf() to disable buffered stdout like other posts have suggested, I have also tried using fflush(stdout). But output is always the same.

When I redirect output to a file like this

```
./main.out > output.txt
```

Output looks good. I understand that this works because when redirecting output to a file, the system does it by buffering the entire output, not just line buffering.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NO_ERROR 0
#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

void childProcess();
void parentProcess();

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int pid = (int) fork();

    if(pid < 0)
    {
        puts("Error: Fork process failed");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        childProcess();
    }
    else
    {
        parentProcess();
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}


void childProcess()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int pid = (int) getpid();
    sprintf(buffer, "This line is from Child pid %d\n", pid);
    write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}

void parentProcess()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int pid = (int) getpid();
    sprintf(buffer, "This line is from Parent pid %d\n", pid);
    write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Output in Cygwin looks like this: (Also 1 or 2 new lines are printed after the output)

```
This line is from Parent pid 20016This line is from Child pid 11784
```

Expected output:

```
This line is from Parent pid 20016
This line is from Child pid 11784
```

Tested in another machine, running linux. Output looks different, but still not as expected. Second line prints after the prompt.

```
user@server$ ./main.out
This line is from Parent pid 31599
user@server$ This line is from Child pid 31600
```

Comment: Works on my computer, maybe try in another terminal emulator?

Comment: I think that the problem here is even if `write` is not buffered, that doesn't mean that the OS does not buffer it internally before sending it to the terminal. The only way to have a predictable result would be to synchronize the parent and the child and let only one write when the other has finished writing.

Comment: Does it print two newlines after both those messages?

Comment: @immibis Yes, it does, forgot to mention that. Edited in question

Comment: @MaximeB The output of the original post is on a Cygwin terminal. I also ran it in a linux machine from my university and got different, but still not the expected results. See edit.

Comment: The Linux output you see is becuase the parent exits immediately after printing, without waiting fot the child to complete.  So the shell (which is waiting for the parent to exit) continues and prints its prompt before the child finishes printing its string.  Add a wait call to the parent after printing, and you should get something more like you expect (though the lines may come in either order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two processes are not synchronized, It means that the father and the son are running at the same time. In that case, the output is unpredictable. You can use the `wait()` function for example, for the father to wait the end of the son.

```
void parentProcess(void)
{
    wait(NULL);  // father is sleeping until his son dies
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int pid = (int) getpid();
    sprintf(buffer, "This line is from Parent pid %d\n", pid);
    write(1, buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```